# With or without an asterisk when incrementing pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

In "void pointers" example in the tutorial on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), I try to compare like following. Why do we still need `*` in parenthesis? What is happening when no `*`?

```
void increase(void* data, int psize) {
    if (psize == sizeof(char)) {
        char* pchar;
        pchar = (char*) data;
        cout << "pchar=" << pchar << endl;
        cout << "*pchar=" << *pchar << endl;
        //++(*pchar);   // increases the value pointed to, as expected
        ++(pchar);      // the value pointed to doesn't change 
    } else if (psize == sizeof(int)) {
        int* pint;
        pint = (int*) data;
        //++(*pint);   // increases the value pointed to, as expected
        ++(pint);      // the value pointed to doesn't change 
    }
}

int main() {
    char a = 'x';
    int b = 1602;
    increase(&a, sizeof(a));
    increase(&b, sizeof(b));
    cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Update after accepting solution) I try to make clear what I didn't get, based on @Cody Gray's answer. The address of `pchar` is incremented to point to nonsense location. But because variable `a` in `main` is `cout`ted instead of `pchar`, this `cout` still prints a value that somewhat makes sense (in this example it would be 'x').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The `*` operator *dereferences* the pointer.**

Therefore, this code:

```
++(*pint)
```

increments the value *pointed to by* `pint`.

By contrast, this code:

```
++(pint)
```

increments the *pointer itself*, `pint`. This is why the value pointed to by the pointer doesn't change. You're not changing the value pointed to by the pointer, but rather the value of the pointer itself.

Incrementing a pointer will cause it to point to an entirely different value in memory. In this case, since you only allocated space for a single integer, it will point to a nonsense value.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a cast from pointer to other pointer

```
char* pchar;
pchar = (char*) data;
```

you telling to compiler to process this memory as char pointer, in which you could perform pointer arithmetic to this variable. Therefore, you are not working with the value of the pointer just with pointer, that's is a memory address in which you are making the arithmetic.

To work with the value you need to use "*" or access to memory pointer by the char.